# Ext.define and handler scope

Tags: extjs4

I got exactly the same problem as http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?140992-Ext.define-and-the-Scope and unfortunately there's no clear answer on the thread.

I know that `scope:this` won't work since it will only change the scope from the button to the **window**, and based on my search and the suggestion given on the thread, I conclude that the only solution is

1. define the alias when extending grid panel.
2. traverse the DOM using `this.up('alias')` to get the grid panel.

Is it *really* the only solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on the example from the post, try this...

```
initComponent: function() {

    ...
    var me = this;

    me.tbar = [
        {
            text: 'Start',
            iconCls: 'icon-start'
        }, {
            text: 'Stop',
            iconCls: 'icon-stop'
        }, {
            text: 'Eintrag hinzufügen',
            iconCls: 'icon-add',
            scope: me,
            handler: function() {
                me.addEntry();
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The scope in handlers in components are usually the instantiated component of which's handler was called. That button in the tbar is actually a component, and its instantiated form becomes the scope. You should traverse to your Panel like you said to get the object you want.